# How to change registration username max_length in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

In the file `0008_alter_user_username_max_length.py`, as a migration, the help text for the registration template is shown, along with the max username length setting for names. Altering this file and then pushing the migration, however, does not work. What have I done, and how may I change the username `max_length` and `help_text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` model and migrations are on the Django side, you can't just change those migrations.

If you want to change things in the `User` model, you need to create a custom user. If the only thing you want to do is change the username max length, it's not so tough. This should be enough:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=1000,  # Or whatever.
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 1000 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

You'll want to take the username field from Django's code, so you get all the help text, validators, etc., this one is from the current master.

Then you need to set this in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "my_app.MyUser"
```

This will only work reliably for new projects. If you have an existing project, or you don't want to create your own user model, and you want to constrain the max_length *below* the one in the model, you can do this validation in your form instead of the model.

[Documentation for overriding / etc. the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/).